# DVISVGM and PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, dvips, dvi-mode

EPS file conversion is not satisfactory with `dvisvgm` because labels are not displayed.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
  \usepackage{etex}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,nccmath}
  \usepackage{pstricks}
  \usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-bezier,pst-tree,pst-sigsys,pst-grad,pst-all}
  \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
  \begin{document}
  \TeXtoEPS
  \psset{xunit=4cm,yunit=2cm,algebraic=true,arrowscale=1.2}
  \begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5) 
  \psgrid[gridwidth=0.6pt,subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0,gridcolor=lightgray,xunit=0.25,yunit=0.5](-6,-6)(10,5)
 \psaxes[linewidth=1pt,Dx=1,Dy=1,labels=none,ticksize=-3pt 0pt]{->} (0,0)(-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5)
 \psxTick[ticksize=-3pt](1.25){\frac{5}{4}}
 \psxTick[ticksize=-3pt](0.666666666666){\frac{2}{3}}
 \begin{psclip}
 {\psframe[linestyle=none](-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5)}
 {\psplot[linewidth=0.8pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{1.25}{6*x-3}}%
 {\psplot[linewidth=0.8pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{1.25}{1-(2-3*x)^2}}%
 \end{psclip}
 \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt](0,1)(0.666666666666,1) (0.666666666666,0)    
 \uput[dl](0,0){O}
 \uput[d](1,0){I}
 \uput[l](0,1){J}
 \uput[ur](1.25,-2){$\mathscr{C}_{f}$}
 \uput[ur](0.75,1){$\mathscr{C}_{g}$}
 \uput[d](2.42,0){$x$}
 \uput[l](0,2.35){$y$}
 \end{pspicture}
 \endTeXtoEPS
 \end{document}
```

Compiled with this simple `Makefile`:

```
 all:
    latex fichier.tex
    dvips -Ppk -V -E -o fichier.eps fichier.dvi
    dvisvgm -E --libgs=/usr/lib/libgs.so.9 fichier.eps fichier.eps
    gpicview fichier.svg
```

Comment: I get an error `! Use of \psaxes@ii doesn't match its definition.`

Answer (score 5):

- it makes no sense to use the environment `TeXtoEPS`
- spaces between arguments of `\psaxes` are not allowed
- there is no need for using the eps file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,nccmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}

  \psset{xunit=4cm,yunit=2cm,algebraic=true,arrowscale=1.2}
  \begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5) 
  \psgrid[gridwidth=0.6pt,subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0,gridcolor=lightgray,xunit=0.25,yunit=0.5](-6,-6)(10,5)
 \psaxes[linewidth=1pt,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-3pt 0pt]{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5)
 \psxTick[ticksize=-3pt](1.25){\frac{5}{4}}
 \psxTick[ticksize=-3pt](0.666666666666){\frac{2}{3}}
 \begin{psclip}{\psframe[linestyle=none](-1.5,-3)(2.5,2.5)}
   \psplot[linewidth=0.8pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{1.25}{6*x-3}
   \psplot[linewidth=0.8pt,plotpoints=2000]{0}{1.25}{1-(2-3*x)^2}
 \end{psclip}
 \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt](0,1)(0.666666666666,1) (0.666666666666,0)    
 \uput[dl](0,0){O}
 \uput[d](1,0){I}
 \uput[l](0,1){J}
 \uput[ur](1.25,-2){$\mathscr{C}_{f}$}
 \uput[ur](0.75,1){$\mathscr{C}_{g}$}
 \uput[d](2.42,0){$x$}
 \uput[l](0,2.35){$y$}
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

with the sequence:

```
latex fichier.tex
dvisvgm --libgs=/usr/lib64/libgs.so.9 child.dvi
```

However, there is a problem with the correct math font.

Comment: There's no problem with the math font but with the SVG viewer. :) Call dvisvgm with option `-n` to create an SVG file that can be rendered correctly by most SVG viewers.

Comment: @Herbert Rather the sequence : `dvisvgm child.dvi`

Comment: @ Martin This actually seems to work with the sequence `dvisvgm -n fichier.dvi`, even though I'll have to change the position of some labels in the source file.

Comment: @Fabrice Can you give us some more information? The positions of what labels do you have to adapt? The generated SVG and the PS file created with dvips look almost identical to me.

Comment: @Martin It's ok !!